# localStorage not working in Edge?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, microsoft-edge

I am currently working on a some JS. It works fine in every browser apart from Microsoft Edge.
The issue is quite simple:
at the beginning of one of my scripts I declare a variable like so:

```
var something = localStorage.getItem('something');
```

Anyway the something doesn't exist yet, but the whole idea is that this can be used for reference in a later function. Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari don't have a problem with this but Edge does, so my question is, is the a quick fix?
Or am i going to have to rewrite my whole script because of Edge?

This is the error that edge throws by the way.

```
 Unable to get property 'getItem' of undefined or null reference
```

Thanks!

Comment: try. `localStorage['something']`

Comment: When I tried it in IE, it doesn't throw error. Can you add more code that you're writing?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bg142799%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Still getting the same error. How ever i have used Win 10 since beta. Which means that even though i now have the official version it could possibly still have some bugs left in?

Comment: Can't reproduce this on Windows 10 Edge. `localStorage.getItem('something') // null`. Are you sure you've spelled `localStorage` right? You're not declaring a `var localStorage` anywhere are you, hiding the native window object?

Comment: @RGraham If that it should not work in other browsers too.

Comment: Are you accessing the file locally on your machine? It needs to be on a server.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal True. But if the code is representative it shouldn't work on my Edge either. I didn't want to leave a sole "doesn't work" comment and offer some incentive for the OP to go back and look at the code

Comment: @zfrisch that's wrong..

Comment: @BhojendraNepal I apologize, you're right.

Comment: I spelled everything right. As i said it works in all the other browsers. And yes i am running it out of windows, not on a localhost. But since when is that an issue?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Local Storage [didn't work for local files in IE9](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jprosise/using-html5-web-storage-for-interprocess-communication), so I imagine that this is still the case in MS Edge.

I just tested it in Edge with a server on `localhost` and your line of code worked just fine:

```
> var something = localStorage.getItem('something');
> undefined
```

It is possible that this was a security issue in earlier versions of IE and was just never updated as the browser was developed.

Although, it appears that localStorage and sessionStorage still don't work in [Edge for HTML files accessed using the 'file://' protocol.](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8816771/)

Comment: Thank you! Go to love Microsoft!

Comment: Further to this issue discussed. Although localStorage was working for me, also in IE browsers on localhost, for a single-page app. When I tried setting and accessing the property on multiple pages, it behaved unexpectedly; it only seemed to update for the current url (indivdual page). In the end I decided I would have to only test in IE when online.

Comment: This was answered almost 5 years ago. Has this been resolved for edge?

Comment: @LewisMenelaws Sadly no. I came here for a solution and found this question. It appears as of writing this comment, it is not updated. Using the latest edge right now. Version 84.0.522.59 (Official build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try

```
var something = window.localStorage.getItem('something');
```

Could you also check if you have 'Enable DOM Storage' selected? You can find it under:
Internet Options -> Advanced tab -> Security group box

Also if you are running your page from local filesystem, localStorage doesn't work on IE, you have to run it from the web server.

[Here is a link that provides more information of how to enable it](https://danieladeniji.wordpress.com/2015/06/08/javascript-error-unable-to-get-property-getitem-of-undefined-or-null-reference/)

Comment: Nope keeps saying the same thing.

Comment: before that have you set the variable named `something` in to local storage?. using `localStorage.setItem`

Comment: @Niels, I updated my answer with more information, please take a look.

Comment: @VladBezden I have tried this but without any luck. I have cookies enabled as well.

Comment: @Niels, are you running your page from your local disk (file://...) or you load page from the server? Looks like localStorage doesn't work on IE from local file.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for solution older version of browser to also work to store key value for using between pages.
logic could be

```
function detectIE() {
            var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;

            var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
            if (msie > 0) {
                // IE 10 or older => return version number
                return false;
            }

            var trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
            if (trident > 0) {
                // IE 11 => return version number
                return false;
            }

            var edge = ua.indexOf('Edge/');
            if (edge > 0) {
                // Edge (IE 12+) => return version number
                return false;
            }

            // other browser
            return true;
        }
```

then to set key value use something like this

```
if (detectIE()) { window.localStorage.setItem('key1', value1);window.localStorage.setItem('key2', value2);}else{ setCookie('key1','value1',1);var value1 = getCookie('key1');}

function setCookie(name,value,days) {
var expires = "";
if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
    expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
}
document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";}

function getCookie(name) {
var nameEQ = name + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
}
return null;}
```

also you can erase the cookie

```
function eraseCookie(name) {   
document.cookie = name+'=; Max-Age=-99999999;';  }
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is adding needless complexity. You'd have to fetch your value in a different way, as well as setting differently. If you want localStorage, stick with localStorage. So you can always use localStorage.getItem(whatever)

Comment: Edge and IE do not support that. So you have to achieve it with cookie.

Comment: IDGI: Edge and IE support basic localStorage just fine. See compatibility chart at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: It support with latest versions only what about users with older version ?So storing with cookie is best policy, So before down voting give deep thought

Comment: Ok. I'll grant you that. As a SAAS product, my company decrees we only have to support latest versions (to IE11, which works with localStorage as well) -- thank goodness. But your comment should have been more specific instead of blanket "Edge and IE do not support" -- that's not true in latest.

Comment: I have updated my answer wording. Please acknowledge.

Comment: Better, though I'm not certain about your detection function. Might be better ways to do that; I didn't test it.

Comment: that function could be reference to understand how can we find version of a browser. its programmers choice to check for predicate.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe DOMStorage is turned off? Test with this:

```
if (typeof window.Storage === 'undefined') {
    alert('Storage turned off...');
}
```

Comment: `typeof window.Storage` still returns `function` but calls to localStorage throw.  (This is dumb, but unsurprising.)