# AngularJS LocalStorage in local files

Tags: angularjs, cookies, local-storage

I want to know if it is possible to save values into the local storage of Edge, if all files are only locally (file://...)?

I didn't managed to replicate the results of this plnkr in a local file, but it is working online excellent in the plnkr.

http://plnkr.co/edit/3vfRkvG7R9DgQxtWbGHz?p=preview

```
    $scope.$storage = $localStorage.$default({
      x: 42
    });
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32375000/511374

Comment: yes, explains that it might not work (tested it now in different Browsers, it worked except Edge), but is there maybe another solution? f.e. any experience with IndexedDB?

Comment: I guess it'll not work as well. Security reasons. Why do you need such thing? Maybe something like http://electron.atom.io/ can help.

Comment: Need it due to sensitive data, which has to stay offline, makes a lot things harder. i will have a look at electron and parallel try to trick edge to bypass ist security guidelines.

Comment: You should not try that. Because every file that will run from local fs will have access to your sensitive data. That's why it's not working in a first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to due it great in Google Chrome and Firefox, it seems to be only a Edge problem.

Answer (score 0):

So generally it's supposed to work like that. Because every file opened from local fs will have access to that localStorage.  Same story with development servers on localhost. So if you really like to have local app with isolated (yet not secured from being stolen) localStorage you still need to host it on server. LocalStorage will be 'secure' for a given user on his local machine.